# pdo bind_param containing quote returns nothing

Tags: pdo, quote, bindparam

I'm converting a mysqli code into PDO as it was requested but I'm having a hard time trying to pass some single quotes into the new LIKE query.I will only paste the parts regarding this problem as there's no need of pasting the whole query etc I guess.

Whenever I use something like "whatever" it returns the results fine, but when I go for "what'ever" it doesn't return anything... The way I have it at the moment was working with mysqli_ but it doesn't when I changed everything to PDO. Any idea how to actually quote the string or escape it properly?

Thank you in advance.

My variable is

```
$FilterRaid="%{$_POST['FilterRaid']}%";
```

The query

```
$listbugs = $bugtrackerpdo->prepare('
...
INNER JOIN raid ON raid.ID = bugs.Raid
AND raid.RaidName LIKE :raid
...
'); 

$listbugs->bindParam(':raid', $FilterRaid);
$listbugs->execute();
```

Comment: there is no difference between PDO and mysqli in this regard. Quotes do not have any special meaning in LIKE statements. Check your data. I mean **check your data**

Comment: I mean check your data. Write a proof of concept code. Two code snippets, PDO and mysqli-based alongside, that selects only the string in question and nothing else. And you will see that there is NO difference.

Comment: @YourCommonSense well, you have a point there. My database has : `Ahn&#039;Qiraj ` in so it wasn't getting the `&#039l` in the place of `'`. But I don't understand why it was working with mysqli... At least I found out where the problem is... Thank you!

Comment: probably you had this quote encoded as well when using mysqli

Comment: @YourCommonSense once again you are correct. I had forgotten to do nl2br on my <option> values once more when I was re-writing the code. Thank you for everything.. Also your "The only proper guide on PDO" is probably something that I'll learn by heart at the moment I already went in there and saw numerous "fixes" to update my code better. Thank you again for everything.